# What is the redline for different gears for Peugeot 107 2005 model?

Tags: transmission, gears, peugeot, gear-ratio

I have a Peugeot 107 which is a 1 liter engine car.

I was wondering what is the maximum safe speed at different gears?

The car starts to make a lot of noise in 1st and 2nd gear, even at 10 mph at 2nd gear the car makes too much noise.

Comment: Is it a new car? And by noise what do you mean , can you be more specific as to weather engine noise or other.

Comment: Engine speed its governed by the redline, the gear does not affect the engine speed per se.  What type of driving are you doing? racing? commuting? town/highway? basically you should use your ears and have a bit of mechanical sympathy.  If it sounds wrong chances are it is.

Comment: You also need to define what the noise is. Are you talking about engine noise? Gear train noise? Road or environmental noise? *What noise* is too loud. Also consider that the Peugeot 107 is a *small car*. It won't be as quiet as a Mercedes S600. You pay a small amount for a vehicle, you get a small amount of car ... nature of the beast.

Comment: @Anarach, I'm not that much concern about the noise. I'm more interested in the speed limit of each gear, lets say on a flat road. What is the maximum speed i can change to the second, third and so forth gear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your car  has an engine designed with city based environments in minds so you will have a short gear ratio meaning you will have to shift lot of gears in the city but on the other hand car will be economical.

To determine optimal shifting time you need to look at the power graph of your car, the picture below shows the dyno of your car.

[image]

If you follow the the bottom line you can know that your car produces peak HP at around 3000 RPM so if you want better acceleration and performance shifting at around 2800 to 3000 RPM will be optimal.

However if you want economy shifting at 2000RPM will prove much efficient.

The speed however depends on the load the car is carrying and other factors which is not possible to theoretically determine. You need to observe that and shift accordingly.

It is never recommended to change gears at the maximum RPM for a city car since  you will get very very less gas mileage and  **is harmful** for your engine in the long run.

After all that, Changing gears still depends on a lot of factors which can only be determined by you when you drive, as a bonus I googled and got the below info on your car's shifting speeds.

**I cannot gurantee authenticity of the below information and  i do not endorse the below speeds Just use for reference**

1 st gear : as short as possible

2 nd gear: to 35/40 max

3 th gear: 40-60km

4 gear : 60-85

5 gear : 70-> km